# How to accept powershell input in MB [int]

Tags: powershell

How can you force a user input to be in MB and not the default KB/Decimal?
Let's say I have a function with `ValidateRange` min/max parameter. I would like the user to input numbers in MB and not KB, is that possible?

Example:

```
Function Get-Bigfiles 
{ 
    param ( 
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [ValidateRange(1MB,100MB)] $Size 
    ) 

    Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32 | `
        Where-Object {$_.Length -gt $Size -and !$_.PSIscontainer} 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

User input does not have any unit coming with it. `5` is 5. It's neither 5 litres nor 5 pounds nor 5 MB nor KB.

If you want an input of 150 mean 150 MB, then that's fine. When you check against filesize, which is given in bytes, you will need to multiply your 150 by 1024 to have the same number in KB and by 1024 again to have the number of bytes.